# Jquery datatable fnFilter is not work in some conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

In my code i use fnFilter function of Jquery datatable to search the data. 
In some cases it search perfectly but in some cases it not.
if i try to search code = "BS" it will search perfectly.
But when i try to search using code = "AL" it will display all records. which is not correct.
This is my code for datatable search option.

```
 $("div.dataTables_filter input").bind('keypress', function (e) {
    var searchText = $(this).val().trim();
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $("#search-error-text").remove();
        if (searchText.length > 0) {
            var value = searchText;
            oTable.fnFilter(value);

            $("div.dataTables_filter input").val(searchText);
        }
        else {
            var errorMessage = "Please Enter Data!";
            $("div.dataTables_filter input").before("<span id='search-error-text' class='error-text'>" + errorMessage + "</span>");
            return;
        }
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
});


$("div.dataTables_filter #grid-search-button").click(function () {
    $("#search-error-text").remove();
 var searchText = $("div.dataTables_filter input").val().trim();
    if (searchText.length > 0) {
        var value = searchText;
        oTable.fnFilter(value);
        $("div.dataTables_filter input").val(searchText);
    }
    else {
        var errorMessage = "Please Enter Data!";
        $("div.dataTables_filter input").before("<span id='search-error-text' class='error-text'>" + errorMessage + "</span>");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Html code below table.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="datatable-sale" class="datatable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="table_heading table-head ">
                    Code
                </th>
                <th class="table_heading table-head">
                    Description
                </th>
                <th class="table_heading table-head">
                    Type
                </th>
                <th class="table_heading table-head cursorDefault">
                    Edit
                </th>
                <th class="table_heading table-head cursorDefault">
                    Status
                </th>
                <th class="table_heading table-head cursorDefault">
                    Delete
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="table-head">
            @foreach (var item in ViewData["sale"] as IEnumerable<Sales_lut>)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td class="table_heading text-left table-head-maintenance Width-10">
                        @item.code
                    </td>
                    <td class="table_heading text-left">
                        @item.descrip
                    </td>
                    <td class="table_heading text-left table-head-maintenance Width-10">
                        @item.type1
                    </td>
                    <td class="table_heading">
                        <a id="edit_sale" href="#" class=" edit action-button permission-based-access" saleidval="@item.saleid" permission-key="@Permissions.Sale.GetText()" sale-code="@item.code">
                            <i class="icon-pencil input-icon success" title="Edit">
                            </i>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="table_heading permission-based-access" permission-key="@Permissions.Sale.GetText()">
                        @if (item.status == 0)
                        {
                            <a class="active" href="" title="Change Status" active-id="@item.saleid" sale-code="@item.code" active-code="@item.code">
                                <img id="active" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/tick.png")" />
                            </a>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <a class="in-active" href="" title="Change Status" in-active-id="@item.saleid" sale-code="@item.code" in-active-code="@item.code">
                                <img id="in-active" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/bullet_cross.png")" />
                            </a>
                        }
                    </td>
                    <td class="table_heading">
                        <a id="delete_sale" class=" deletesale delete permission-based-access" permission-key="@Permissions.Sale.GetText()" href="#" sale-code="@item.code">
                            <i class="icon-trash" title="delete">
                            </i>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Attach screenshot display an actual issue.Code "FZ" and "AM" does not contain any word as "AL" then also it display this records. and this happen for multiple search options. I need to apply search for whole data so i can't use single column search option.I just find out one issue that it search alternate rows means it search only odd rows in the grid. Any solution for it ???
[image: Result after searching code "AL"]

Comment: Try `oTable.fnFilter("^" + value + "$");` filter by exact match

Comment: if we used above option then search is not work. it display No record found.

Comment: please show your html data!

Comment: Now i add my Html code also.

Comment: It's working forme https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/7kfmyw6x/121/

Comment: But i need to use foreach loop to iterate over all records. otherwise it works fine.